# Next.js active nested links

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Does anyone know why the following might be not be working:

```
<li className={router.asPath.startsWith('/archive/website') ? 'active' : ''}>
```

... using Next.js. It is returning the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
```

This works fine:

```
<li className={router.asPath == '/archive/website' ? 'active' : ''}>
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you using SSR, where ```router``` would be undefined? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Ah yeah I am using ISR as I'm getting data from headless WP.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like ```router && router.path && router.asPath.startsWith(...)```? Try logging ```router.isReady```, it'll probably be false when you're getting the error, so checking if ```router``` and ```router.asPath``` is defined should fix it

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help. Fixed with `router && router.pathname && router.asPath.startsWith(...)` :)